# Why do I get logged out of my Mac account when running this Python code in VStudio Code?

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code

Everytime I run this in VSstudio code, it loads for a second and then the screen goes back, and I have to log back into my laptop main user account, I think the problem has something to do with me using a virtual environment or something? I never had this problem up until a couple of days ago. I was tinkering around in the shell a little while ago trying to get beautiful soup to run, I think I got anaconda to run in a virtual environment or something? Sorry for the lack of clarity I'm kind of new at this.

```
from tkinter import *

# var = Tk() declares a window to be made
root = Tk()
root.title("Simple Calculator")
#Entry(window name,m width, borderwidth) creates a subwindow
FirstSubWindow = Entry(root , width = 35, borderwidth = 5)
FirstSubWindow.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3, padx = 10, pady = 10)

#SecondBar = Entry(root, width = 35, borderwidth = 5)

# Column span dictates the number of columns that the subwindow 
#Will occupy


#FirstSubWindow.insert(0,"Enter your name") , adds test in main 
windo

#SecondBar.grid(row = 1, column = 1, columnspan = 1, padx = 10, 
pady = 10)


# .get() function returns text in the accessed subwindow
def button_click(number):
    CurrentNumber = FirstSubWindow.get()
    FirstSubWindow.delete(0,END)
    FirstSubWindow.insert(0,str(CurrentNumber) + str(number))

def Clear_function():
    FirstSubWindow.delete(0, END)

def addFunction():
    global operatorChecker
    operatorChecker = 0
    firstNumber = FirstSubWindow.get()
    #Global variables can be used outside of function they are 
     #written in
    global fnum 
    fnum = int(firstNumber)
    FirstSubWindow.delete(0,END)


#Can Change global variables down the path by declaring global 
#again!
def multiplyFunction():
    global operatorChecker
    operatorChecker = 1
    firstnumber = FirstSubWindow.get()

    global fnum2
    fnum2 = int(firstnumber)
    FirstSubWindow.delete(0,END)


def equalsFunction(): 

    secondNumber = FirstSubWindow.get() 
    FirstSubWindow.delete(0,END)
    if operatorChecker == 0:
        FirstSubWindow.insert(0, fnum + int(secondNumber))
    elif operatorChecker == 1:
        FirstSubWindow.insert(0, fnum2 * int(secondNumber))


# Padx controls width of box/button, pady height
button_1 = Button(root, text = "1", bg = 'black', padx = 40, pady 

= 20, command = lambda: button_click(1))

    button_2 = Button(root,bg = 'blue', text = "2", padx = 40, 
pady = 20, command = lambda: button_click(2))
    button_3 = Button(root, text = "3", padx = 40, pady = 20, 
command = lambda: button_click(3))
    button_4 = Button(root, text = "4", padx = 40, pady = 20, 

command = lambda: button_click(4))
    button_5 = Button(root, text = "5", padx = 40, pady = 20, 
command = lambda: button_click(5))
    button_6 = Button(root, text = "6", padx = 40, pady = 20, 
command = lambda: button_click(6))
    button_7 = Button(root, text = "7", padx = 40, pady = 20, 
command = lambda: button_click(7))
    button_8 = Button(root, text = "8", padx = 40, pady = 20, 
command = lambda: button_click(8))
    button_9 = Button(root, text = "9", padx = 40, pady = 20, 
command = lambda: button_click(9))
    button_10 = Button(root, text = "0", padx = 40, pady = 20, 
command = lambda: button_click(0))

#Operator functions
button_multiply = Button(root, text = '*',padx = 40, pady = 20, 
command = lambda: multiplyFunction())
button_add = Button(root, text = "+", padx = 39, pady = 20, 
command = lambda: addFunction())
button_equals = Button(root, text = '=', padx = 49, pady = 20, 
command = lambda: equalsFunction())
button_clear = Button(root, text = 'Clear', padx = 35, pady = 20, 
command = lambda: Clear_function())
button_1.grid(row = 3, column =0 )
button_2.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
button_3.grid(row = 3, column = 2 )
button_4.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
button_5.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
button_6.grid(row = 2, column = 2)
button_7.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
button_8.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
button_9.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
button_10.grid(row = 4, column = 0)
button_clear.grid(row = 4, column = 2, columnspan = 2)
button_equals.grid(row = 5, column = 2, columnspan = 1)
button_add.grid(row = 5, column = 0)
button_multiply.grid(row = 5, column = 1, columnspan = 1) 



root.mainloop()
```

The traceback is as follows:

```sh
source /opt/anaconda3/bin/activate
conda activate base
(base) Joshuas-MacBook-Pro:PycharmProjects joshua$ source /opt/anaconda3/bin/activate
conda activate base
/opt/anaconda3/bin/python /Users/joshua/PycharmProjects/FirstProjects/SimpleCalculator.py
(base) Joshuas-MacBook-Pro:PycharmProjects joshua$ conda activate base
(base) Joshuas-MacBook-Pro:PycharmProjects joshua$ /opt/anaconda3/bin/python /Users/joshua/PycharmProjects/FirstProjects/SimpleCalculator.py
(base) Joshuas-MacBook-Pro:PycharmProjects joshua$
```

Comment: Are you saying this works if you run this from the terminal outside of VS Code?

Comment: I actually haven't tried that, ill do it and get back to you.  But what has been happening is that I'll just run it as usual in VS code, and while it used to work for me, after messing around in the shell it kicks me out of my mac account.